# visjs timeline disappears after angular route reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have wrapped a visjs timeline into an angular directive. When I call `$route.reload()` in the outer controller the timeline disappears. After the page reload completes, the directive still has a reference to the original timeline object and the dom element does not appear to change.

Does anyone know what could cause it to just disappear?

I have created a plunkr but I don't know how to reload the route inside a plunker since that would change the url.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hwShQ2iYR7TOcILSBcEY?p=preview

```
function timelineViewer() {

  var timeline;
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      var items = new vis.DataSet();
      var container = document.getElementById('vis-timeline');

      var options = {
        height: 100,
        width: 600,
        zoomMin: 1000 * 60 * 2,
        zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 20
      };

      items.clear();
      items.add($scope.data);

      timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);

      console.log('Reloading directive ...')
    },
    template: '<div id="vis-timeline"></div>'
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reload the route is needed to setup a route for the controller, see this [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/XruShSpkzFh7dpBPcgsi?p=preview) of your plunker.
It seems work well with your implemented directive, then I'm not sure about the cause, later I add some changes expecting to fix the problem

Explaining the plunker:

```
controller: function($scope, $element) {
  var items = new vis.DataSet();
  var container = $element[0];
```

The angular's directive already has a reference to the DOM element of itself (`$element`), so it can be safely used instead of getting it through `document.getElementById`

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  console.log('Destroying directive ...')
  timeline.destroy();
});
```

This lines ensure to destroy the timeline when the directive is destroyed, the timeline has the method `destroy()` to clean the affected DOM elements